# ngModel value is undefined in add function

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a window to add/edit a rule.

I have a component "Rule Edit" to edit or create a rule.
The edit part works fine but when I try to add a rule I got an error in the selectors:
`ERROR TypeError: _co.rule.selectors is undefined`

RuleEditComponent.html:

```
        <div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutGap="10px">
            <div class="sub-labels" fxFlex="50%;">
                <label i18n>IP</label>
            </div>
            <div fxFlex="50%;">
                <input id="ruleedit-ipsource" type="text" autofocus [(ngModel)]="selectors.ip" <--- error here
                    [disabled]="!permEditConfig" formControlName="ip">
            </div>
        </div>
```

Add/Edit functions:

```
    addRule() {
        const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(RuleEditComponent, {
            data: { rule: new Rule() },
            width: '600px',
            disableClose: false,
        });

        dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe((result) => {
            if (result) {
                this.reloadRules();
            }
        });
    }

    editRule(rule: Rule & { actionsLocked: boolean }) {
        rule.actionsLocked = true;
        this.actionsLocked = true;
        this.configService.rule(rule.id, rule.type).then((rule: Rule) => {
            const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(RuleEditComponent, {
                data: { rule },
                width: '600px',
                disableClose: false,
            });

            dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe((result) => {
                if (result) {
                    this.reloadRules();
                }
            });
        }).catch(() => {
            this.notifier.notify('error', 'Couldn\'t get rule details');
        }).finally(() => {
            this.actionsLocked = false;
            rule.actionsLocked = false;
        });
    }
```

Server side selectors is a dict in python which can be empty.

I'm stuck because I don't know how to solve this undefined error.

Comment: Please, show the code of your modal dialog as well. How do you assemble and place the new rule? Usually you should return it with  `afterClosed()` and then push it into your local list. How do you do it?

Comment: @akromx First your rule is object of Rule class then it must instantiate first, alternatively you can use *ngIf="rule" then go for rule.selector.

Comment: @Lynx242 I'm not sure it's relevant to show this. The error occurs when I open the window to add a rule, not when I save.

Comment: @GaurangDhorda I have to add *ngIf="rule" in each input with ngModel="rule.selectors." ? I tried but the error is still there.

Comment: have you create instance rule or not ?

Comment: https://bet365techblog.com/default-values-typescript#:~:text=TypeScript%20Default%20Property%20Values,time%20the%20class%20is%20instantiated.&text=var%20TestA%20%3D%20%2F**%20%40class%20*%2F,value%20%3D%200%3B%20this. just follow this rule

Answer (score 0):

This is probably happening because the selectors (and ipSource in it) property of the rule object has not been initialied.

So, before you do anything with that object, you need to initialize it with a default value (or, patch it in case of editing).

```
const rule = new Rule();
rule.selectors = new Selectors();
rule.selectors.ipSource = ''; // or, something
```

Now, pass this to the `dialog.open()` as this:

```
data: { rule },
```

Also, add optional chaining like this:

```
[(ngModel)]="rule?.selectors?.ipSource"
```

Answer (score -1):

When you say something like this

```
data: { rule: new Rule() }
```

you generate an object of type Rule. That's a fact. But it is only an empty hull. All your attributes are not set but `undefined`. You have to fill them at least with dummy values, if necessary.

This is why you get the error.

If you want to get around it, you can use the Elvis-Operator `?.`

```
<div fxFlex="50%;">
    <input id="ruleedit-ipsource" type="text" autofocus 
    [(ngModel)]="rule?.selectors?.ipSource"
    [disabled]="!permEditConfig" formControlName="ipSource">
</div>
```